# truth tables and validity of arguments

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

1. $ p $
2. $ p \to q $
3. $ \lnot q \lor  r$
4. $ \therefore r$

In order to prove validity with truth tables, do 1) 2) and 3) have to be true in order for the conclusion to be true?

Comment: Try omitting on of the first three propositions, and see if you can still derive the conclusion

Answer (score 2):

A valid argument is an argument **IF** the premises are true, **then** the conclusion must be true. That is, for an argument to be valid, we must have that the truth of the premises guarantee/entail the truth of the conclusion.

An argument can be valid even if one or more of the premises are false. Provided the premises ***logically entail*** the conclusion, the argument is valid. If we know the premises to be true, in a valid argument, we then know the conclusion is true. If we don't know the truth values of the premises, we can show such an argument is valid if we can show that, "if the premises are/ were true, then the conclusion is necessarily true."

Whether or not the premises are true is another question: for example, a *sound* argument requires that the argument be *valid* and that the premises are all true.

Comment: Roy wants to show validity of argument $p$. Then, what he has to show is that "if the premises are/ were true, then the conclusion is necessarily true". The cases of $p$ being true while some of the premises might not be, are out of question, right?

Comment: @frabala - what does it mean "validity of argument $p$" ? A formula is *valid* (in prop calculus a *tautology*) and $p$ is not (no single prop letter is) *or* an argument is, in which case (as per OP's answer) must be something like : "from A and B and .., X follows".

Comment: This answer doesn't talk about proving validity with truth tables.

Comment: Hey, @Doug, do you frequent Philosophy.SE? If so, is logic a tag there? Do you see more logic there, or here?

Comment: @amWhy I've been there a few times.  I haven't gone there recently though.  There is a logic tag there.  There's currently 426 questions there tagged logic at philosophy (beta), and it's the tag with the most number of questions.  There's 3,954 questions tagged logic here.  Some questions at philosophy.stackexchange I'd expect would come as off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks, Doug! (Philosophy was one of my three undergrad majors, then went off to earn a master's degree in philosophy, before turning to pursue graduate studies in math.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is an easy one and you do not necessarly have to "write down" all the truth table.

In order to prove with truth tables that

> $\Gamma \vDash r$

where $\Gamma = \{p, p \rightarrow q, \lnot q \lor r \}$ we apply the definition :

> $\Gamma$ *tautologically implies* $\alpha$ (written $\Gamma \vDash \alpha$) iff every 
>   truth assignment for the sentence symbols in $\Gamma$ and $\alpha$ that satisfies every member of $\Gamma$ also satisfies $\alpha$.

In this case, we can "play a little bit" with the definition. We rephrase it in the equivalent form :

> there is **no** truth assignment for the sentence symbols in $\Gamma$ and $\alpha$ that satisfies every member of $\Gamma$ and does not satisfy $\alpha$.

Proving this with truth-tables amount to showing that there is no rows in the tt where all the formulas in $\Gamma$ are evaluated to *true* and the formula $r$ is evaluated to *false*.

We can take benefit of the fact that $\lnot q \lor r$ is equivalent to $q \rightarrow r$.

Let we start: we assume a truth assignment $v$ such that, for all $\varphi \in \Gamma$, $v(\varphi)=true$.

We have $v(p)=true$, and by truth-functional property of $\rightarrow$, also $v(q)=true$, in order $p \rightarrow q$ to be *true*.

So $v(r)=true$, for the same reason (we have assumed that, for the truth assignment $v$, $\lnot q \lor r$, i.e. $q \rightarrow r$, is *true*).

In conclusion, the truth assignment $v$, such that all the premises (the formulas in $\Gamma$) are *true*, boils down to the row of the tt corresponding to : *t, t, t*.

For this truth assignment $v$, $r$ is *true*; but $v$ is a generic truth assignment that satisfies all the *premises*, so we cannot have a truth assignment that satisfy all the premises and that evaluates $r$ to *false*.

In conclusion, we have proved that :

> > $\{p, p \rightarrow q, \lnot q \lor r \} \vDash r$.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant in my answer. Ok, I have to admit I should be more analytic. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by definition $\Gamma\vDash p$, if $p$ is true whenever $\forall \gamma\in\Gamma$, $\gamma$ is true.

Here, $\Gamma$ contains (1), (2) and (3).

Comment: An argument can be valid even if one or more of the premises are false. Provided the premises logically entail the conclusion, the argument is valid. If we *know* the premises to be true, in a valid argument we then know the conclusion is true. If we don't know the truth values of the premises, but can show such an argument is valid if we can show that, "*if the premises are/ were true*, then the conclusion is necessarily true."

Comment: @amWhy I think this is the same, because $(A_1\wedge_\cdots\wedge A_n)\to B$ is logically equivalent to $A_1\to(A_2\to\cdots\to(A_n\to B)$. I don't see were is your disagreement, here.

Comment: But note an implication requires the following: "IF" the antecedent is true, then the conclusion is true. An implication holds when every the antecedent (premises) is false, as well. Logical entailment is even stronger. It requires that IF the premises are true, then so must be the conclusion... We classify an argument as valid or not valid strictly on the basis of whether the conclusion necessarily follows from the premise, even when we know nothing about the truth values of the premises. $$(p \rightarrow q),\;p\;$$ guarantees $q$, regardless of whether p, q are true or what they mean.

Comment: @amWhy I still think we're saying the same thing. $(p\to q), p\vdash q$ holds, because whenever $p$ is true and $(p\to q)$ is true, $q$ is also true.

Comment: @amWhy no he is saying quite the opposite, the question is about "when is an argument valid?" while this answer answers "what is a valid argument". Hope he changes his answer otherwise I will need to vote it down (and i don't like that)

Comment: @frabala no you are saying quite the opposite, the question is about "when is an argument valid?" while your answer answers "what is a valid argument". Hope you will change your answer otherwise I will need to vote it down (and i don't like that)

Comment: @Willemien I really don't get it. The question is "When is an argument valid?". I answer on this by "an argument is valid when it is true whenever the premises are true". So, he has to suppose that formulas (1), (2) and (3) in OP are true.

Comment: @amWhy - I agree with your answer, but I'm puzzled by your comment; unless you are invoking *modal logic* in the metatheory, when you say " Logical entailment is even stronger [than conditional]. It requires that **IF** the premises are true, then so **must** [emphasis mine] be the conclusion... We classify an argument as valid or not valid strictly on the basis of whether the conclusion **necessarily follows** [emphasis mine]" are you using the "modal" adverbs to convay what ? 1/2

Comment: Standard def like Henderton's are "$\Sigma$ *taut implies* $\tau$ iff every truth assignment for the sentence symbols in $\Sigma$ and $\tau$ that satisfies every member of $\Sigma$ also satisfies $\tau$. And we have that: $\alpha \vDash \beta$ iff $\vDash \alpha \rightarrow \beta$. In concl, my understanding is that the "semantical view" does not differ from the *conditional*: an argument is *valid* also when the premises are false for the same reason that the conditional is true when the antecedent is false. Of course, we can have $\vDash$ also without $\rightarrow$ .... 2/2

Comment: @frabala Okay, I was a bit harh, (and at the end i didn't downvote your answer) but i just like long answers that explain not just a yes or no , and a tiny bit of tekst, we are a bit here to educate eachother

Comment: To be precise, "$p$ is true whenever $\forall \gamma \in \Gamma$, $\gamma$ is true" is the definition of $\Gamma \vDash p$ and **not** of $\Gamma \vdash p$, that must be read as "$p$ is *provable* from $\Gamma$"...

Answer (score 0):

The question calls for a look at the truth table proving the validity of the argument set out, so here it is.

It reveals that propositions 1) and 2) in the original argument can be false when the conclusion "r" is true. So in those cases the answer to the question is no.

Interestingly though, when proposition 3) is false, so is r. So 3) has to be true for r to be true.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, 1., 2., and 3. do not have to be true in order to prove validity with truth tables.

You can prove the valid argument

(p $\land$ $\lnot$ p)

∴

q

using truth tables as follows:

```
  p   q   ¬p  (p ∧ ¬ p)  q
  F   F   T      F       F
  F   T   T      F       T
  T   F   F      F       F
  T   T   F      F       T
```

Consequently, you could prove the following argument:

1. (p $\land$ $\lnot$ p)
2. r
3. s

   ∴

   q

with truth tables.